# How to Install Hot towel SPA on Visual 2013, I cannot see the template in the web section

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, hottowel

EDIT: I forgot to say that on my machine there was VS2012 installed either, sorry.

I tried with VS2013 but it did't work for me, may be I am missing something.

Creating a new project I've chosen Visual C# -> Web than a Web Application and I cannot see the Jhon Papa's hot towel template within it

I have installed, I guess correctly the file HotTowelSpa.2013.vsix but I still cannot see the template at all.

I even tried to install the package with an SPA web app opened, with the following steps

```
Tools -> Lybrary package Manager -> Package Manager Consol
```

and I wrote this string

```
PM> Install-Package HotTowel.
```

It seems that every was installed but when I try to run the project it doesn't show the Papa's Home template. Where I am wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I've found the solution thanks this link http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1eb8780d-d522-4dcf-bf56-56f0eab305c2 read the post named VS 2013 VSIX template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly download and run the [Hot Towel Spa (VS 2013)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1eb8780d-d522-4dcf-bf56-56f0eab305c2) vsix file.

Then in Visual Studio navigate to : File --> New Project --> Template -> Visual C# --> Web --> Visual Studio 2012 and select ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application:

[image]

From here you should see HotTowel SPA in the templates list:

[image]

Comment: when I open this there is no "Hot Towel SPA". Trying to reinstall the VSIX I get the error message "This extension is already installed to all applicable products".

Comment: @AsleG download and install it first.

Comment: The issue was though somehow related. It turned out I hadn´t updated my VS 2012 with the latest update [4]. I uninstalled the extension and updated VS, then after updating VS, reinstalled the Hot Towel VSIX. Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In the link you find in the comment above you can find the solution that I've reported here, wrote by

Ado77

```
If you have VS 2012 and VS 2013 installed, the template gets installed under the 2012 sub template section in 2013.
```

Answer (score 0):

When selecting Single Page Template on the right panel there is the option "visual 2012". Select it, then you can select Single Page Hot towel template.